# ¿Cómo hacer que cambie el $PS1 al hacer cd?

Tags: bash, rutas

Tengo un problema en *Bash* con el *$PS1*... Cuando hago `cd` no me cambia la ruta.

***/etc/profile***

```
PS1="$PWD "
export PS1 USER LOGNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC EDITOR TERM
```

Al iniciar *Bash*:

```
/ 
/ cd /root
/
```

Como ven, sigue siendo `/`, ¿Es por el `cd` o por el `$PS1` que sucede esto?

¿Se puede solucionar?, y si es así ¿Cómo se soluciona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El PS1 puede ser configurado atraves de ciertos parmetros  por así decirlo para personalizar el prompt.  Entre ellos está el \w que es el que muestra el current directory.

```
PS1="[\w] $"
```

Comment: Mejor así... `PS1="\[\e[1;32m\]\w\[\e[0m\] "`